# IThit Ajax browser 2.0

Tags: ajax, applet, ithit-ajax-file-browser

It states on the ItHit site that applet is optional for Ajax browser, is this true? can we use the Ajax browser without using the applet, will I just be able to browse the server files immaterial of MS or non-MS doc types? Can a client use a local windows explorer and just drag and drop files into the ajax browser window?

Answer (score 0):

The applet is optionnal, it serve to browse your webdav directory with your current Operation system and also edit a file using available software.

You can customize your menu to hide those two options.
[example](http://www.webdavsystem.com/ajaxfilebrowser/programming/context_menu_customization/)